# conflict between luatexko and accents packages

Tags: luatex, accents, incompatibility

The following code doesn't compile.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{luatexko}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

What can I do to remove the conflict?

Comment: they both want to redefine `\acute` (and other accents) do you want `\acute` to be the accents package or luatexko package version (it can be either, but not both at the same time)

Comment: I understood `luatexko` to be the luatex version of `kotex`.  If I replace `luatexko` with `kotex` and compile using `pdflatex` it compiles fine.

Comment: But to answer your question: I'd like one in math mode, the other in text mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

You can solve this by loading `fontspec` with the `no-math` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexko}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha!  Loading luatexko with no fontspec appears to work, also, albeit that appears to be using different fonts.